# Function on a Power Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, fixed-point-theorems, lattice-orders

Let $f\colon \mathcal{P}(A)\mapsto \mathcal{P}(A)$ be a function such that $U \subseteq V$ implies $f(U) \subseteq f(V)$ for every $U, V \in \mathcal{P}(A)$. Show there exists a $W \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ such that $f(W) = W$.

This is what I've been thinking:

Notice $A \subseteq A$ therefore $f(A) \subseteq f(A)$ and as $f(A) \in  \mathcal{P}(A)$, this implies $f(A) \subseteq A$.

Then $f(f(A)) \subseteq f(A) \subseteq A$ and so $f(f(f(A))) \subseteq f(f(A)) \subseteq f(A) \subseteq A$.

If $A$ is finite, this process should leave you with the desired $W$ (I think) after a finite number of iterations. Not so sure about the infinite case.

I might even be going about this totally wrong so any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can continue your construction transfinitely...

Comment: @ZhenLin: Sounds yucky and unnecessary (also, this is sometimes an exercise given long before transfinite recursion is taught).

Comment: @ZhenLin what do you mean by transfinitely?

Comment: @user229177: If you are unfamiliar with transfinite recursion (or transfinite induction), you should definitely ignore that comment. To give a brief explanation, transfinite recursion is a generalization of recursion on the natural numbers, which you seem to want to use in the finite case. It allows us to go beyond the natural numbers and venture into the ordinals, which are a generalization of the natural numbers themselves. Again, if you're unfamiliar with these things, it's fine, you don't really need that in order to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is the Knaster-Tarski theorem, actually. Let me give you a hint forward.

And you're essentially on the right track, but instead of constructing it transfinitely, what happens when you look at all the sets $\{B\mid f(B)\subseteq B\}$? What would their intersection be?

Comment: would that just give you another set which satisfies f(C)⊆C?

Comment: Yes, but what would that mean?

Comment: If we let T ={B ∣ f(B)⊆B}, then  f(∩T) ⊆ ∩T ⊆ T. But ∩T is the smallest set of T which holds the property so f(∩T) = ∩T?

Comment: That is indeed correct.

Comment: Phew, got there eventually. Thanks a lot!